# Constrained Maximization Algorithm with Linear Contours

Tags: optimization, algorithms, extreme-value

**The Original Problem**

Let $M(X)$ be a function of a multivariate random variable $X$ with probability density function $f_X(X)$. Given a small positive real number $\alpha$, find $m_{\alpha}$ such that

\begin{equation}
\int\mathbb{1}_{M(X)\leq m_{\alpha}}f_X(X)dX=\alpha
\end{equation}

---

**One Solution**

The following solution comes from "Linear, yet attractive Contour", Juan Cardenas, Emmanuel Fruchard, Jean-Francois Picron, Credit, Jan 2001

Let $X\sim\mathcal N(0,\Sigma)$ and $M(X)$ have **linear contours**. In other words, $M(X)=C$ is (if not empty set) a plane or hyperplane for any $C \in \mathbb{R}$. We further assume that $M(X)$ is smaller than $C$ on the side of the contour that contains the origin, and greater than $C$ on the other side of the contour.

Let $B^{T}B=\Sigma$. Define a new coordinate system (random variable) $Y$ such that $X=\Phi^{-1}(\alpha)B^{T}Y$, where $\Phi$ is the cumulative density function of the standard normal. The original problem (for reasons I cannot understand) is equivalent to the constrained maximization problem

\begin{equation}
m_{\alpha} = \smash{\displaystyle\max_{||Y||=1}} M(Y)
\end{equation}

---

The implementation steps are (and my comments are in the parentheses)

1. Compute the matrix $B$ (I can do this by Cholesky decomposition)
2. Compute a vector of (global) sensitivities of $M$ with respect to the variables (What are *sensitivities* and what variables, $X$ or $Y$?) Using this linear assumption (which I think is the assumption of linear contours), the maximum $M$ is found at the starting point:

\begin{equation}
y^{(0)} = \frac{B\delta}{||B\delta||}
\end{equation}

3. As long as the desired precision (so $\delta$, undefined in the equation above, is *precision*?) has not been reached, do the following, for $i=0$ to ...

   a)  Compute the gradient of $M$ in terms of the original variables at the point $X^{(i)}$.

   b)  Using the Jacobian of the two coordinate transformations, obtain the gradient in spherical coordinates.

   c) Do one step of a maximazation routine (eg., conjugate gradient) in spherical coordinates and get the new point back in terms of the original coordinates, $X^{(i+1)}$

I am not at all familiar with the algorithm in step 3 (a through c). I searched for Conjugate Gradient Method in Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method), but it doesn't involve any spherical coordinates. Any references (theory or numerical examples)  are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Something important must be missing from your formulation: although your original objective function depends on "$f$" (whatever that might be), neither the subsequent transformations or formulations involve $f$ at all!

Comment: Thank you.  Although you have now described $f$, it still vanishes from the scene immediately, showing that the problem you have described (constrained maximization of $M$) bears no relationship to the problem you began with (find a region enclosing a given probability of $f$).  Which of these two different problems are you trying to ask about?

Comment: According to the paper ("Linear, yet attractive Contour", Juan Cardenas, Emmanuel Fruchard, Jean-Francois Picron, Credit, Jan 2001), finding the contour $m$ that gives the probability of $\alpha$ is equivalent to solving the constrained maximization. Unfortunately, I don't understand why that is the case.

Comment: Apparently, you have omitted or altered some aspect in the retelling of the problem.  I can guess some likely interpretations, but in all of them there is no need for the involved algorithm you describe.  As I explained in a comment to one of your previous questions on this topic, the problem (as you have stated it) enjoys a huge simplification: having linear contours means it's only a univariate problem rather than multivariate. There must be a lot more going on here than you have been able to describe so far.