# What are some of the methods for constrained maximization?

Tags: optimization, extreme-value, constraint

This question is related to a [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/284958/constrained-maximization-algorithm-with-linear-contours) that I asked earlier. Since I am not able to decipher the algorithm in the original question, I would like to know whether there are other algorithms that can help me achieve the same goal.

Here is the question:

Let $X \sim \mathcal N(0,\Sigma)$. Let $M(X)$ be a function of $X$ whose contour is linear. Let $B^TB=\Sigma = \text{cov}(X)$. Given $\alpha=0.05$, let $Y$ be a transformation of $X$ such that $X=\Phi^{-1}(\alpha)B^TY$, where $\Phi$ is the cumulative density function of $\mathcal N(0,1)$. How do I find

\begin{equation}
\smash{\displaystyle \max_{||Y||=1}M(Y)}
\end{equation}

Comment: The phrase "contour is linear" is so specific and unusual that I would like to confirm its meaning.  To me, it means that all sets of the form $M^{-1}(c)$ for real numbers $c$ are either empty or are lines. If that's the case, then $M$ can be written $M(X) = f(X\beta^\prime)$ for some fixed vector $\beta$ and arbitrary function $f$ *of one real variable.*  Is this what you mean?  If so, then your question simplifies considerably, because $X\beta^\prime$ can be assumed to have a standard Normal distribution; and if not, then what do you actually mean?

Comment: @whuber, your interpretation of "linear contour" is correct.

Comment: Thank you.  Notice that your question has nothing to do with $X$ or much else about the statistical situation: after the simplification I mentioned, observe that you are asking how to optimize an arbitrary function of one real variable defined on an interval.  Methods for that typically are the subject of a longish chapter in any book on numerical methods.  The textbooks categorize those methods according to the properties of $f$: whether it is continuous, how differentiable it might be, whether you can supply bounds on the magnitudes of it derivatives, and so on.

Comment: Thank you @whuber! Could you please elaborate how "linear contours" leads to the statement that "... then $M$ can be written $M(X) = f(X\beta')$ for some fixed vector $\beta$ and arbitrary function $f$ of one real variable"? Do you mean, for example, $X \in \mathbb{R}^{1\times2}$,  $\beta' \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times1}$, then $X\beta' = \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2$?

Comment: "Linear contours" implies $M^{-1}(c)$ is a disjoint union of hyperplanes for any $c$. Suppose $H_1,H_2$ are such hyperplanes for $c_1\ne c_2$. These hyperplanes cannot intersect (the value of $M$ on any intersection point would be both $c_1$ and $c_2$), whence they are parallel, implying there exists a nonzero linear form $\beta$ for which $\beta$ is constant on each of the $H_i$. It follows that $\beta$ is uniquely determined by $M$ and that for all $x$, $M(x)$ is determined by $\beta(x)$. Defining $f(y)=M(x)$ for *any* $x$ for which $\beta(x)=y$ gives $M(x)=f(\beta(x))$, *QED*.

Comment: An example would be $M(x_1,x_2)=\sin(x_1+2x_2)$. This has linear contours. You may choose $\beta$ to be $\beta(x_1,x_2)=x_1+2x_2$ and you can write $M(x_1,x_2)=f(\beta(x_1,x_2))$ for $f(y)=\sin(y)$. You may also use any multiple of this $\beta$, such as $\alpha=3\beta$. In that case define $g(y)=\sin(y/3)$: now $M(x_1,x_2)=g(\alpha(x_1,x_2))$. The situation is that simple and obvious in all cases where $M$ has linear contours.